# How to plot graphs on their corresponding sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, plot, charts

I am taking data from multiple spreadsheets and plotting them on a chart, for each of the respective spreadsheets. I want the data from Spreadsheet1 to plot a graph also on Spreadsheet1. Currently, my code plots all of the graphs on the last sheet, so the graphs for sheets 1,2,3, etc are all plotted on the last sheet. I am unsure how to fix this as I am new to VBA. I recorded a macro to get the code to plot the data.

here is my plotting code:

```
For j = 1 To size
'creates chart

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter).Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementLeft 696.75
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementTop -81.75
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleWidth 1.3333333333, msoFalse, _
    msoScaleFromTopLeft
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleHeight 1.6909722222, msoFalse, _
    msoScaleFromTopLeft
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Length and Depth Data"""
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Worksheets("Case " & overview(j, 1)).Range("$R$10:$R$6000")
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = Worksheets("Case " & overview(j, 1)).Range("$S$10:$S$6000")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""B31G MAOP"""
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = Worksheets("Case " & overview(j, 1)).Range("$C$10:$C$159")
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = Worksheets("Case " & overview(j, 1)).Range("$I$10:$I$159")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Name = "=""B31G 1.25SF"""
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).XValues = Worksheets("Case " & overview(j, 1)).Range("$C$10:$C$159")
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Values = Worksheets("Case " & overview(j, 1)).Range("$J$10:$J$159")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).Name = "=""B31G 1.39SF"""
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).XValues = Worksheets("Case " & overview(j, 1)).Range("$C$10:$C$159")
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).Values = Worksheets("Case " & overview(j, 1)).Range("$P$10:$P$159")
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-126
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 8
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
Range("W32").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter).Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 2").IncrementLeft 311.25
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 2").IncrementTop 213
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=18
Range("AD46:AD47").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 2").ScaleWidth 1.3145833333, msoFalse, _
    msoScaleFromTopLeft
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 2").ScaleHeight 1.4930555556, msoFalse, _
    msoScaleFromTopLeft
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Length and Depth Data"""
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Worksheets("Case " & overview(j, 1)).Range("$R$10:$R$6000")
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = Worksheets("Case " & overview(j, 1)).Range("$S$10:$S$6000")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""MB31G MAOP"""
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = Worksheets("Case " & overview(j, 1)).Range("$C$10:$C$159")
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = Worksheets("Case " & overview(j, 1)).Range("$N$10:$N$159")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Name = "=""MB31G 1.25SF"""
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).XValues = Worksheets("Case " & overview(j, 1)).Range("$C$10:$C$159")
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Values = Worksheets("Case " & overview(j, 1)).Range("$O$10:$O$159")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).Name = "=""B31G 1.39SF"""
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).XValues = Worksheets("Case " & overview(j, 1)).Range("$C$10:$C$159")
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).Values = Worksheets("Case " & overview(j, 1)).Range("$P$10:$P$159")
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-117
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "B31G Burst Curve"
Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "B31G Burst Curve"
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 16).ParagraphFormat
    .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
    .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
End With
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 16).Font
    .BaselineOffset = 0
    .Bold = msoFalse
    .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
    .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
    .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
    .Fill.Transparency = 0
    .Fill.Solid
    .size = 14
    .Italic = msoFalse
    .Kerning = 12
    .Name = "+mn-lt"
    .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
    .Spacing = 0
    .Strike = msoNoStrike
End With
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Select
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-12
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "B31G Burst Curve"
Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "B31G Burst Curve"
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 16).ParagraphFormat
    .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
    .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
End With
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 4).Font
    .BaselineOffset = 0
    .Bold = msoFalse
    .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
    .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
    .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
    .Fill.Transparency = 0
    .Fill.Solid
    .size = 14
    .Italic = msoFalse
    .Kerning = 12
    .Name = "+mn-lt"
    .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
    .Spacing = 0
    .Strike = msoNoStrike
End With
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(5, 12).Font
    .BaselineOffset = 0
    .Bold = msoFalse
    .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
    .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
    .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
    .Fill.Transparency = 0
    .Fill.Solid
    .size = 14
    .Italic = msoFalse
    .Kerning = 12
    .Name = "+mn-lt"
    .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
    .Spacing = 0
    .Strike = msoNoStrike
End With
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "MB31G Burst Curve"
Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "MB31G Burst Curve"
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 17).ParagraphFormat
    .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
    .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
End With
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 17).Font
    .BaselineOffset = 0
    .Bold = msoFalse
    .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
    .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
    .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
    .Fill.Transparency = 0
    .Fill.Solid
    .size = 14
    .Italic = msoFalse
    .Kerning = 12
    .Name = "+mn-lt"
    .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
    .Spacing = 0
    .Strike = msoNoStrike
End With

Next j
```

Comment: You will want to create the chart With the respective sheet (End With).  The data would need to be specified out as Sheets("NAME").Range("ERB").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in a completely different way. But a quick fix to the wall of code that you provided would be adding this to the beginning just right after your for loop starts:

```
For j = 1 To size
  'creates chart

      Worksheets("Case " & overview(j, 1)).Activate

    'Rest of the code would be the same
    '...

Next j
```

You should read this question and its answers:

[How to avoid selecting and activating in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Answer (score 1):

You apply all instructions on the `ActiveSheet`. You can select specific sheets by `Sheets(1).Activate` or `Sheets("sheet_name").Activate`.

You can also iterate over all sheets by

```
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If sht.Name Like "..." Then ...
Next sht
```